# How to add condition for 1st Iteration in views-view-fields.html.twig file

Tags: theming

I am trying to implement a carousel , inside my **views-view-fields--block_1.html.twig** , I want to add  **active** class inside the div for the first Iteration . I have added the code in twig file but every time it is adding active class for all the iteration.

**code snippet:**

```
{% if fields.counter.content == 1 %}
{% set tag = "active" %}
{% else %}
{% set tag = "" %}
{% endif %}
```

In my view title,body,image and result counter fields are there . From result counter i am getting the value and comparing inside the above twig file. Can anyone give suggestion, how to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: This is weird, if anything, your problem should be the other way around, where the tag is always empty. How can the counter be 1 for all rows? Try doing a `{{ fields.counter.content }}` and see what number shows up.

Comment: Did you try quoting the 1? So fields.counter.content == "1" - I could imagine that the field content renders to a string value and your unquoted condition evaluates to true as it checks whether the content is set. (Can't fiddle on a template right now, as I'm not in my office.)

Comment: Thanks giving for suggestions , fields.counter.content == "1" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your code snippet is within a for loop, you could use either `loop.first` or `loop.index` in your if statement to target the first iteration. 
 Refer to https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Thus your twig template would probably resemble:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if loop.first 1 %}
    {% set tag = "active" %}
  {% else %}
    {% set tag = "" %}
  {% endif %}

... render row/field with class in template ...
{% endfor %}
```